# Laravel dot notation deeply return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two config files: **father_categories.php** and **childs_categories.php**

In my local development (I´m using Windows) I can access to my array config files in Laravel /config folder and works perfectly.

But my production server is Linux, and this deep config files return null in some cases.

For example child categories array return me null in production:
[image]

But if you access to config(childs_categories.php); return the categories perfectly:

[image]

This is my **father_categories.php** file complete:

```
<?php

return [

    #### Father categories ####


    'cine-series-tv' => array(
         'url_segment' => 'cine-series-tv',
         'menu_item'   => 'Cine, Series y TV',
         'name'        => 'Cine, Series y TV',
         'title'       => 'Cine, Series y TV',
         'meta'        => 'de Cine, Series y TV con tus personajes favoritos o frases míticas. Regalos para seriéfilos y cinéfilos.',
         'cat_type'    => 'primary',
         'cat_father' => '',
         'childs_categories' => array(
            config('childs_categories.harry-potter'),
            config('childs_categories.juego-de-tronos'),
            config('childs_categories.marvel'),
            config('childs_categories.rick-and-morty'),
            config('childs_categories.star-wars'),
            config('childs_categories.pokemon'),

        ),
        'description'    => 'de tus películas o series favoritas. El regalo ideal para el cinéfilo o seriéfilo de la casa.',
       'extra_description' => ''

    ),

    'videojuegos' => array(
         'url_segment' => 'videojuegos',
         'menu_item'   => 'Videojuegos',
         'name'        => 'Videojuegos',
         'title'       => 'videojuegos',
         'meta'        => 'de videojuegos, para los fans de videjuegos míticos o más modernos de las consolas actuales.',
         'cat_type'    => 'primary',
        'cat_father' => '',
        'childs_categories' => array(
            config('childs_categories.grim-fandango'),
            config('childs_categories.pokemon'),
            config('childs_categories.pixelart'),

        ),
        'description'    => 'de tus videojuegos favoritos, el regalo ideal para el gamer de la casa.',
       'extra_description' => ''
    ),


];
```

And this is my **childs_categories.php** file:

```
<?php

return [


    #### Subcategories ####
   'juego-de-tronos' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'juego-de-tronos',
       'menu_item'    => 'juego de tronos',
       'name'    => 'juego de tronos',
       'title'          => 'Juego de tronos',
       'meta'           => 'de Juego de Tronos con diseños de los personajes, Stark, Targaryen, etc',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('cine-series-tv'),
       'visible_for' => array('1728','5570','1661','3333','6092','@7'),
       'description'    => 'de <strong>Juego de Tronos</strong> o Game of Thrones para comprar con los emblemas y casas de los Stark, Lannister, Targaryen, etc. Los personajes de la famosa serie cobrarán vida, ¿de qué bando estás?',
       'extra_description' => ''
    ),
    'star-wars' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'star-wars',
       'menu_item'     => 'star wars',
       'name'         => 'star wars',
       'title'          => 'star wars',
       'meta'           => 'con diseños de star wars basadas en este maravilloso universo de La Guerra de las Galaxias.',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('cine-series-tv'),
       'visible_for' => array('1728','5570','1661','3333','6092','@7'),
       'description'    => 'de star wars con diseños del universo de La Guerra de las Galaxias. Darth Vader, Han Solo y compañía te acompañarán en tus desayunos.',
       'extra_description' => ''

    ),
    'harry-potter' => array(

           'url_segment'    => 'harry-potter',
           'menu_item'     => 'harry potter',
           'name'         => 'harry potter',
           'title'          => 'harry potter',
           'meta'           => 'de Harry Potter con diseños de Ron, Hermione, Gryffindor, Slytherin, Hogwarts, etc.',
           'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
           'cat_father' => array('cine-series-tv'),
           'visible_for' => array('1728','5570','6092','@7'),
           'description'    => 'de Harry Potter con diseños basados en sus personajes y referencias del fantástico mundo de Hogwarts. ¡Regala pura magia!.',
           'extra_description' => ''

      ),
    'pixelart' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'pixelart',
       'menu_item'    => 'pixelart',
       'name'    => 'pixelart',
       'title'          => 'Pixelart',
       'meta'           => 'de pixelart, con la nostalgia de los videojuegos de antaño estilo megadrive, nintendo, gameboy, y mucho más.',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('videojuegos'),
       'visible_for' => array('5570'),
       'description'    => 'estilo pixelart recordando a los videojuegos retros de la época de megadrive, atari, nintendo nes, game boy y muchos más.',
       'extra_description' => ''
    ),
    'pokemon' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'pokemon',
       'menu_item'     => 'pokemon',
       'name'         => 'pokemon',
       'title'          => 'pokemon',
       'meta'           => 'pokemon basadas en la serie o en los videojuegos de Game Boy',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('cine-series-tv','videojuegos','pixelart'),
       'visible_for' => array('1728','5570','1661','3333','6092','@7'),
       'description'    => 'pokémon ideales para los fans de la serie y de Pikachu o los videojuegos de la época de la Game Boy.',
       'extra_description' => ''

    ),
     'marvel' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'marvel',
       'menu_item'     => 'marvel',
       'name'         => 'marvel',
       'title'          => 'marvel',
       'meta'           => 'marvel con diseños no oficiales, basados en los cómics y personajes.',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('marvel','comic','heroes','superheroes'),
       'visible_for' => array('5570','1728'),
       'description'    => 'de marvel, con tus superheroes favoritos como Spiderman, Deadpool, los Xmen, Capitán América, IronMan y muchos más.',
       'extra_description' => ''

    ),
    'grim-fandango' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'grim-fandango',
       'menu_item'    => 'grim fandango',
       'name'    => 'grim fandango',
       'title'          => 'Grim Fandango',
       'meta'           => 'con diseños del videojuego Grim Fandango, mítica aventura gráfica de PC cuyo protagonista es Manny Calavera.',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('videojuegos'),
       'visible_for' => array('1728','6092','@7'),
       'description'    => 'Grim Fandango, popular videojuego de aventura gráfica de PC cuyo protagonista es Manny Calavera.',
       'extra_description' => ''
    ),
    'rick-and-morty' => array(

       'url_segment'    => 'rick-and-morty',
       'menu_item'    => 'rick and morty',
       'name'    => 'rick and morty',
       'title'          => 'de Rick and morty',
       'meta'           => 'de Rick and morty',
       'cat_type'  => 'secondary',
       'cat_father' => array('cine-series-tv'),
       'visible_for' => array('1728','5570','3333','6092','@7'),
       'description'    => 'de Rick y Morty, la serie de animación de ciencia ficción más ácida y divertida que existe actualmente.',
       'extra_description' => ''
    ),
];
```

Comment: Could you go in the folder where the configs are stored and run `ls -lah`?

Comment: So is this Laravel 5.2 or 5.3? You are experiencing permission issues (most likely). You should always access config files/keys/values using `config(file.key)`.

Comment: All permissions is right. Is laravel cache config files problem?

Comment: I´m using php artisan config:cache but the error persist.

Comment: @marijnz0r I think the problem is that I repeat the name "childs_categories" in both files. And Linux give me problems with that, and windows not.

Comment: @Kyslik I think the problem is that I repeat the name "childs_categories" in both files